# How to find store and find the highest value in an array?

Tags: arrays, sorting

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class P4 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    final int NUMMONTHS = 12;
    final int SORT = 12;
    int [] plantHeight = new int[SORT];
    int [] avgTemp = {46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 55, 51, 47};
    int [] avgRain = {5, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4};
    int[] newGrowth;
    newGrowth = new int[NUMMONTHS];
    int minTemp;
    int maxTemp;
    int minRain;
    int j;

    //prompt user input
    System.out.println("Welcome to the 210 gardening planner!"); 

    System.out.println("Enter minimum temperature for plant:");
        minTemp = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter maximum temperature for plant:");
        maxTemp = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter minimum rainfall for plant:");
        minRain = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Month" + "\t" + "Temp Rain Growth" + "\t" + "Plant Height");

    //Calculate and print plant growth
    for(j=0; j<NUMMONTHS; j++){
        if(avgTemp[j] >= minTemp & maxTemp >= avgTemp[j]){
            newGrowth[j] = avgRain[j] - minRain;
            if(j == 0){
            plantHeight[j] = newGrowth[j];
            }else{
            plantHeight[j] = newGrowth[j] + plantHeight[j-1];}
        }
        //if growth is zero, height remains same as previous
        else{
            newGrowth[j] = -1;
            plantHeight[j] = plantHeight[j] - 1;
        }
        //plant height cannot be less than 0
        if(plantHeight[j]< 0){
            plantHeight[j] = 0;

        }
        plantHeight[j] = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print(j + "\t" + avgTemp[j] + "   " + avgRain[j] + "     ");

    System.out.println(newGrowth[j] + "            " + plantHeight[j]);

    }
    for (int i=0; i<plantHeight; i++) {
            // find smallest element in elements i to plantHeight
            int currentMin = plantHeight[i];
            int minIndex = i;

            for (int x=i+1; x < plantHeight; x++) {
                if (plantHeight[x] < currentMin) {
                    currentMin = plantHeight[x];
                    minIndex = x;
                }
            }
        if (minIndex != i) {
                    plantHeight[minIndex] = plantHeight[i];
                    plantHeight[i] = currentMin;
            }
        }
    System.out.println(plantHeight[0]);




    }
}
```

I made a graph of plant growth depending on rain and temperature, but I need some help storing the heights of the plant after each month and printing the tallest height. To do so, I'm trying to store each height into an array, then sorting the array in descending order to find the highest value and print it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort) inbuild function to sort and the retrieve the last number.

Here is a simple example to explain `sort`. You can then implement in your code

```
int[] num = {4,3,6,2,9,3};

Arrays.sort(num);

for (int i: num) {
    System.out.println(i);
}

int max = num[num.length - 1];

System.out.println(max);   // max is 9
```

[Demo of Arrays.sort()](http://ideone.com/pddPpk)

Since you want maximum height and its corresponding month, it would be a better idea to use [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and have `height` as key and `month` as value. Since it implements `SortedMap` so the key would be inserted in ascending order by default, you can then retrieve the last entry which would be the maximum height and its corresponding month.

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    map.put(rand.nextInt(100), i);
}

/*for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> a: map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(a.getKey() + " " + a.getValue());
}*/

Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> maxValues = map.lastEntry();
int maxHeight = maxValues.getKey();
int maxMonth = maxValues.getValue();
System.out.println(maxHeight + " " + maxMonth);
```

[Demo of TreeMap](https://ideone.com/0vZdMc)

Comment: Thank you! I was able to find the highest int in my plant heights, but is there also a way to print the month of the highest plant height?

Comment: @TommyTran Why don't you use `Map` instead of two arrays? You can use `sort` on `TreeMap` and store in a `key value` pair

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you show me a sample?

Comment: @TommyTran Okay. I will update my answer with TreeMap example in couple minutes. About my previous comment, `TreeMap` sorts based on `key` inserted so you don't have to explicitly perform `sorting` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sorting, search for maxIndex:

```
    int maxIndex = 0;
    int currentMax = plantHeight[0];
    for (int i=1; i<plantHeight; i++) {
        if (plantHeight[i] > currentMax) {
            maxIndex = i;
            currentMax = plantHeight[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(plantHeight[maxIndex]);
    System.out.println(avgTemp[maxIndex]);
    System.out.println(avtRain[maxIndex]);
```

To find both min and max:

```
    int minIndex = 0;
    int maxIndex = 0;
    int currentMin = plantHeight[0];
    int currentMax = currentMin;
    for (int i=1; i<plantHeight; i++) {
        if (plantHeight[i] < currentMin) {
            minIndex = i;
            currentMin = plantHeight[i];
        }
        else if (plantHeight[i] > currentMax) {
            maxIndex = i;
            currentMax = plantHeight[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(plantHeight[minIndex]);
    System.out.println(avgTemp[minIndex]);
    System.out.println(avtRain[minIndex]);
    System.out.println(plantHeight[maxIndex]);
    System.out.println(avgTemp[maxIndex]);
    System.out.println(avtRain[maxIndex]);
```

Comment: This one still requires traversing. If you add to `TreeMap`, inserts are [O(log(n))](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and we know that maximum element will be the last one

Comment: @sam2090 - true, but adding n elements to TreeMap in order to create the map would take O(n log(n)). Creating the array(s) takes O(n), and searching for min + max takes O(n), so the overall time is still O(n) (only a difference in the constant times n).

Comment: Yes. I agree with you :)